# How to print a variable from another function

Tags: python

Here is the deal, i can't take 'myvariable' outside of part1 because my original code is not like this
After My part1 usage is done my program will do some checking in part2 and i need it to print myvariable tho i have no idea how to call the variable.

Here is my code's simple version

```
def part1():
  myvariable = 7355608|02|20|059

def part2():
  print('Some stuff', myvariable)

part2()
```

Answer (score 3):

Have `part1` return the value that you want to use later, and have `part2` accept the value as a parameter.  Then just pass the value from one function to the next.

```
def part1():
    return 7355608|02|20|059

def part2(myvariable):
    print('Some stuff', myvariable)

part2(part1())
```

Or you could call `part1` from inside `part2`:

```
def part1():
    return 7355608|02|20|059

def part2():
    print('Some stuff', part1())

part2()
```

Comment: Hey Sam! I accidentally edited your code. Please ignore :)

Comment: lol no worries, I added in the suggestion to call `part1` from `part2` :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't print that other variable unless you extract it out of that function OR you declare a global variable. Here's how you'd do it if you returned the variable from `part1` (suggesting this way because global variables are generally not recommended):

```py
def part1():
    myvariable = 7355608|02|20|059
    return myvariable

def part2():
    myvariable = part1()
    print('Some stuff', myvariable)

part2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your variable from other functions then you can use keyword called global.

global variable_name

After this no matter where you declares this you can access this variables anywhere with in the file.

Comment: (Broken [home page](http://sandeepkush.herokuapp.com/): *"Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail"*)